# How to change screen resolution?

Tags: wubi, intel-graphics, resolution

I am using HP G62 laptop and it has intel HD graphics. Screen resolution in ubuntu OS is fixed at 1024 x 768. Plz tell me how to change the screen resolution. Apparently there is no option once I goes to system settings/ display

Answer (score 4):

You can use `xrandr -q` to see what resolutions are available for your display

From the manpage

> Xrandr  is  used  to set the size, orientation and/or reflection of the outputs for a screen. It can also set the screen size.

To change the screen resolution to 1024 by 768, you would type:

```
xrandr -s 1024x768
```

Just use that to change it to the size you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Click Here](http://code.aktel.in/how-to-change-the-resolution-of-our-screen-in-ubuntu/)

```
 $ xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768 --rate 60
  $ xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1024x768 --rate 75
  $ xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1024x768 --rate 75
```