# Can I unlock other resolutions? Its running on 1024x768 and I need 1280x720 or 1920 × 1080

Tags: xorg, resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change screen resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205799/how-to-change-screen-resolution)

I've installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS and it doesn't get my screen resolution right. what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked whether these resolutions are availabe in “Displays” in your system settings?

[image: Screenshot of Display]

If they are not available probably some drivers are missing, if this is the case you have to provide some more information.