# Can I adjust computer display size to fit broken screen?

Tags: display, screen

The right 1/4 of my HP laptop screen is broke and does not display anything. I would like to adjust the display of the screen to fit in the 3/4 of the screen that works. I do not want to change the resolution; I want to change the position and size of the display (kind of like you would a window) so I can see everything. Is this possible in any way? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy try this

- Use `xrandr -q` to see what resolutions are available for your display.
- To change it just write in terminal:

  ```
  xrandr -s 1024x768
  ```

See  [reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205799/how-to-change-screen-resolution)